# Adding a line to a Pandas plot

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I'm currently tracking my internet speed and want to generate a plot of my measurements with a Timestamp, Upload value and Download value.

I'm using this to create the plot

```
df.plot(
    kind='line', 
    x=timestamp_column_name, 
    y=[download_column_name, upload_column_name],
    figsize=(12,5)
)
```

Generated plot:
[image]

Now I would like to add a line to this plot with the constant height of `y=100000` but I can't figure out how to do this correctly. How should I do this with Pandas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [`axhline`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.axhline.html). Since `df.plot()` is a wrapper for matplotlib and returns the Matplotlib axes, which contain all the methods for interacting with the plot, it can be used straight forward as:

```
ax = df.plot( ... )
ax.axhline(y=100000)
```

Comment: I guess it would be useful to mention what's going on, namely that `df.plot()` returns the Matplotlib axes, which contain all the methods for interacting with the plot. After that `ax.axhline()` seems pretty self explanatory!